# HTML: Outlook not rendering correctly email

Tags: html, css, email, outlook, html-email

I have an email which is rendering correctly on webapps and browsers, but on outlook client is not rendering correctly, I've tried setting cellspacing, cellpadding, changing the width and can't get it to render correctly on outlook version 2102 (build 13801.21106)

[image]
[image]

[image: Outlook rendering]

**I've stored the html in this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/w0x7rpvq/ and search for the comment** `<!--issuehere-->`

**On browser looks fine**
[image]

**Update 1**

imagine not aligning correctly (https://jsfiddle.net/7sn95eLz/)

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your layout is made with a table with three cells per row. The first row contain only one cell, matching the width of the cell with the image (`190px`). This is why Outlook is displaying your text in such a narrow width. It works in other browsers because you applied a `display:block;` to the `<table>` containing the full width text. But Outlook on Windows doesn’t understand that.

The solution here is to add a `colspan="3"` to the `<td>` containing the full width text.

```html
<!--issuehere-->
<td colspan="3" class="subtitle" valign="top" style="font-family: 'Open Sans', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 16px; color: #333333; font-weight: normal; padding: 0 0 20px 0; background:red;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</td>
```

Comment: dude! you're awesome, it worked, one last one before we wrap it up, I've got this imagine that is also not aligning correctly in outlook, my paddings are being ignored, so whats required in the column to align it correctly? here is the jsfiddle, I will add the screenshot to the initial question. https://jsfiddle.net/7sn95eLz/

Comment: That has to be because of the image width. I see you have a `width="100%"` on that image. But in the Outlooks on Windows, this doesn't work as you'd expect in CSS (take 100% of the parent’s width). Instead, it applies 100% of the image’s real width. Try applying a pixel width on the HTML `width` attribute (and set a `width:100%` in the style attribute which Outlook will ignore on an image). Also, try applying your padding on a `<td>` instead of on the image itself.

Comment: nice, is fixed also, how do you go about know all the css styles which are ignored by outlook on windows? is there a tool/online webapp where I can paste the code and it will tell me what will be ignored or what to use instead for it to be compatible with outlook?

Comment: [VMail](https://vmail.leopard.in.ua/) does exactly that (based on [Can I email](https://www.caniemail.com/) data).

Comment: Thats great, thanks for the link